# AIX make/makefile : variable assignment is not working

Tags: unix, makefile, aix

Is there some trick with the standard AIX make tool to use dynamic variables?
I wish to make a different directory depending on the underlying hostname:

```
# makefile
thisHOSTNAME=`hostname`

all: $(thisHOSTNAME) makeMyDir

machine-1:
    TMP_DIR=V1

machine-2:
    TMP_DIR=V2

makeMyDir:
    @echo makeMyDir TMP_DIR=$(TMP_DIR)
# mkdir -p $(TMP_DIR)  !! NOT WORKING
```

On running "make all", it turns out that $TMP_DIR is empty!?
The dependency $(thisHOSTNAME) in the target all is resolved correctly, and the corresponding target is executed, but the variable TMP_DIR does not maintain the assigned value it would seem.

$ make all

```
TMP_DIR=V2
makeMyDir TMP_DIR=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backtick syntax is **shell** syntax, not **make** syntax. You can use it as the value of variables that are used in commands, but you can't use it for a target name as in

```
thisHOSTNAME=`hostname`
all: $(thisHOSTNAME) makeMyDir
```

Understand that this becomes

```
all: `hostname` makeMyDir
```

and makes `all` depend on the target `hostname` *including* backticks (which I don't know how to insert here), since dependencies are specified in **make** syntax.

I'm not sure if AIX `make` allows to use the GNU make syntax which would permit

```
thisHOSTNAME = $(shell hostname)
```

If not, you might ponder converting the AIX makefile to a GNU makefile.

Comment: In my tests, the backticks do not pose any problem : yes "all" becomes dependent on a target named like the hostname, and if such a target actually exists (in my example machine-1 & machine-2), make finds the target. This actually works on my machine (AIX 6.1). However, it dies not seem to assign any value to TMP_DIR for these targets

Comment: @Fandango What about calling `make thisHOSTNAME=$(hostname)`? This works with all versions of make, since it is POSIX mandated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the GNU `make` extensions (namely `shell` and `if*`), then it's going to get ugly:

```
# Makefile

all: makeMyDir

thisbox:
    mkdir -vp thisdir

thatbox:
    mkdir -vp thatdir

makeMyDir: $(HOSTNAME)
```

then inject environment variables on invocation:

```
$ HOSTNAME=$(hostname) make -e
```

References:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html

Comment: Does AIX make support `$(shell cmd)`?

Comment: This solution works well if the "make" tool is actually GNUmake with all of it flexibility and options, but unfortunately the make tool I am forced to use is the native make installed on AIX. The native make supports neither $(shell cmd) nor "ifeq" constructs

Comment: @Jens, @Fandango, quite right; the `shell` command is a GNU extension. I've amended my answer to (hopefully) better address AIX make; still working on the lack of `ifeq` support

Comment: I can only see one possibility, which both of you have pointed out, that being setting un environment variable in the environment of the make.I will just wrap the make call in a shell script to set TMP_DIR as appropriate. Thank you